# Simple calcul of a limit superior

Tags: analysis, limsup-and-liminf

What is the limit superior of :
$$
\limsup_{x\rightarrow 10} 1*\mathbb{I}_{x<10}(x)+2*\mathbb{I}_{x=10}(x)+\frac{1}{2}*\mathbb{I}_{x>10}(x) ?
$$
If I take the definition of a limit sup I arrive to 2, but I have a little doubt on my procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Note $f(x)=1*\mathbb{1}_{x<10}(x)+2*\mathbb{1}_{x=10}(x)+\frac{1}{2}*\mathbb{1}_{x>10}(x)$. You have

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
1 * 1 + 2 * 0 + \frac{1}{2} * 0 &= 1 &\text{for } x<10\\
1 *  0 + 2 * 0 + \frac{1}{2} * 1&= \frac{1}{2} &\text{for }x>10
\end{cases}$$ Hence
$$\limsup\limits_{x \to 10} f(x)= 1$$. As for the computation of a limit, you don't take into account the value of the function at the point itself.

Comment: I did not know that we do not take the point itself. In that case what's the $\limsup_{x\rightarrow 10^-}f(x)$ ? And $\limsup_{x\rightarrow 10^+}f(x)$ ?

Comment: Moreover, I have seen 2 differents definitions of lim sup/inf. One from wikipedia that exclude the point in question (your definition), and another one that does not exclude the point (check the book of rockafellar 1970 "convex analysis" section 7 page 51 - https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.convexoptimization.com/TOOLS/ConvexAnalysis.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwjNreW06LTPAhVIK8AKHZHCBuAQFggiMAA&usg=AFQjCNFGmquReawYvXvRXynxaMBsc1sj3g&sig2=1Yf95BNiW0VeYY0MhjCAaw)